# All Files Icon Changed in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8

my Recently all files icons changed in windows 8. I searched in google but still unable to solve. Any help Please?
[image]

But all files opening fine in default program. I just have problem with icons else nothing.

Comment: Do you have a recent restoration point you can use?

Comment: [This](http://support.microsoft.com/mats/windows_file_and_folder_diag) might help.

Comment: @Ramhound Not worked.. :( Please any other help?